# Branch deep link notification is not working

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I was trying to do custom redirection of  after reading parameter of branch io deeplink

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, BlankBranchShareActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("branch", "https://bnc.lt/EcMh/POIo83vYev");

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    String title = "DeepLink";
    String message = "messageDeepLink";
    String summaryText = "summaryText";
    NotificationUtility.createNotification(context, title,
            message, summaryText,
            mNotificationId++, resultPendingIntent,
            CancelNotificationResponse.getPendingIntent(context, messageType));
```

Notification is coming and getting displayed and when I am clicking on notification it is redirecting to BlankBranchShareActivity.class

```
public class BlankBranchShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = BlankBranchShareActivity.class.getName();
private Branch branch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    branch = Branch.getInstance();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    branch.initSession(branchReferralInitListener, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

Branch.BranchReferralInitListener branchReferralInitListener = new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {

        String label = "";
        if (referringParams != null)
            label = "ReferringParams" + referringParams.toString();

        if (error == null) {
            JSONObject json = referringParams;
            onCodeResume(json);
            return;
        }

        if (AppConstants.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStart()" + label + ",Error:" + error);
        }
        openMainActivity();
    }
};

protected void onCodeResume(JSONObject json) {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + "Called" + json.toString());

        /*If nothing is their to-launch immediately Launch Main activity */
        if (json == null || json.toString().equals("{}") || (!json.has(JsonKeys.BRANCH_IO_JOB_SHARE_KEY) && !json.has(JsonKeys.BRANCH_IO_SHARE_TYPE_SHARE_KEY))) {
            return;
        }

        //Do Operation 

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume: " + e.toString());
    }

}

private void openMainActivity() {
    Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivityList.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (branch != null) {
        branch.closeSession();
    }
}
```

}

Whenever I am clicking on link it is giving proper parameter for redirection but 
When I am sending same link with notification I am getting

```
{"+is_first_session":false,"+clicked_branch_link":false}
```

What i might be doing wrong

```
    <activity
        android:name=".BlankBranchShareActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/RegisterActivityTheme">

        <!-- App Link your activity to Branch links-->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!--Test key-->
            <data
                android:host="bnc.lt"
                android:pathPrefix="/cdMh"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <!--Production key-->
            <data
                android:host="bnc.lt"
                android:pathPrefix="/EcMh"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="bnc.lt"
                android:pathPrefix="/EcMh"
                android:scheme="workindia" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_keys"
            android:value="@string/branch_meta_all_keys_for_marking_on_manifest" />

        <!-- Deep link path for auto deep linking -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_path" android:value="workindia/*" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Alex from Branch here: sending Branch links via push notifications is one of the features we don't actually see come up too often, even though it is supported. Could you [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) for our Integration Engineering team to take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Getting "clicked_branch_link:false" is a result of a key mismatch. If you are clicking links from your Test instance, but your app is initializing with your Live key, you will get clicked_branch_link:false.